# Visual Studio: Indentation for JavaScript in <script> tags

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, indentation, visual-studio-2013

VS 2013, trying to get indentation for javascript inside a `<script>` tag consistent.

My general settings are: 2 spaces, insert spaces
My HTML settings are the same, HTML (Web Forms) - same
My Javascript settings are the same

A plain .js file **does use** the proper indentation

But for some reason, within a `<script>` tag specifically, I get:
4 spaces, tabbed.

Comment: Same in VS 2017 years later...